# How to make child tr input checkbox value true in html table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Info:** I want to make a table with parent row and child row. if the parent row is checked then the child rows make also checked until next parent row is not exits

How to checkbox checked of all child row of parent row if parent row is checked until new parent row is.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <!-- parent -->
        <tr id="parent-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject"></td>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- child -->
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- parent -->
        <tr id="parent-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject"></td>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- child -->
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Jquery.js

```js
 $('tbody tr#parent-hr').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

    var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr#parent-hr');
    var targetedRow = currentRow.nextAll('tr#child-hr');

    var targetedCheckbox = targetedRow.find(':checkbox');
    targetedCheckbox.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
   }
 });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unchecked child checkbox on click parent checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70848926/how-to-unchecked-child-checkbox-on-click-parent-checkbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you an example for your reference.

```js
 $('tbody tr.parent-tr').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
    let tbody=$(this).parents("tbody");
    tbody.children("tr.child-tr").find(":checkbox").attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <!-- parent -->
        <tr class="parent-tr">
            <td>Parent 1<input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject"></td>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- child -->
        <tr class="child-tr">
            <td>Child of Parent 1<input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-tr">
            <td>Child of Parent 1<input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-tr">
            <td>Child of Parent 1<input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <!-- parent -->
        <tr class="parent-tr">
            <td>Parent 2<input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject"></td>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- child -->
        <tr class="child-tr">
            <td>Child of Parent 2<input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-tr">
            <td>Child of Parent 2<input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="child-tr">
            <td>Child of Parent 2<input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to find the checked value id?

Comment: You can make use of my code to do so.

Comment: I am already using your code i want to get child-tr `data-id` which is not present now but i am adding in my template

Comment: tbody.children("tr.child-tr").find(":checked") <=it will get all checked checkbox and then you can use for-loop to loop all checkbox , get the attribute value.

Comment: thanks great! would you like to help me if any of child value is find checked then the parent checkbox automatic checked?

Comment: This is the end of this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246070/discussion-between-afi-and-the-knvb).

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $('tbody tr#parent-hr').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

    var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr#parent-hr');
    var targetedRow = currentRow.nextAll('tr#child-hr');

    var targetedCheckbox = targetedRow.find(':checkbox');
    targetedCheckbox.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
   }
 });
 
 const parentInputs = $('#parent-tr input')
 
 
 const checkChildRows = (parentInput, isChecked) => {
   const parentRow = parentInput.closest('#parent-tr');
   let childRow = parentRow.nextElementSibling
   
   while(childRow && !(childRow.id === 'parent-tr')) {
     console.log('run')
     childRow.querySelector('input').checked = isChecked
     childRow = childRow.nextElementSibling;
   }
 }
 
 [...parentInputs].forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  checkChildRows(input, event.target.checked)
 }))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <!-- parent -->
        <tr id="parent-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject">Parent</td>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- child -->
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker">Child</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker">Child</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker">Child</td>
        </tr>

        <!-- parent -->
        <tr id="parent-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject">Parent</td>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- child -->
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker">Child</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker">Child</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="child-tr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ticker" id="ticker">Child</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```